# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.imymemine/files/qwer/abcd.txt (Is a directory)

Tags: java, android, sdk

I met this problem I tried to save a diary entry with a title (as the folder name) and content (diary entry) to external storage.

Have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to my manifest file and created 10MiB to my emulator.

However, it gives me problem. Any idea?

```
public void SavingData(){ 
    String Title = txtTitle.getText().toString();
    String Content = txtContent.getText().toString();

    boolean isWriteable = false;
    boolean isAvailable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        //we can RW the media;
            isWriteable = isAvailable = true;
        }

    else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        isAvailable = true;
        isWriteable = false;
        }else{

        isAvailable = isWriteable = false;

            }

    File sdcard = new File (getExternalFilesDir("MyDiary"), Title);
    File dir = new File(sdcard + "/" + Content +".txt");

    dir.mkdirs();
    try {
        dir.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    if(!dir.mkdirs()){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Directory not created");
        }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir);
        fos = openFileOutput("MyDiary",Context.MODE_APPEND);

        fos.write(Content.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating the `.txt` file as a directory. Rather than all that after

```
dir.mkdirs();
```

you should have

```
sdcard.mkdirs();
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir);
    fos = openFileOutput("MyDiary",Context.MODE_APPEND);

    fos.write(Content.getBytes());

    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Further, rather than

```
File dir = new File(sdcard + "/" + Content +".txt");
```

you'd want to use

```
File dir = new File( sdcard, Content + ".txt" );
```

to avoid the explicit use of the path separator. If you must use it, please use `File.pathSeparatorChar`.

Comment: nothing happens. neither file nor directory is created.

Comment: There's a lot of strange stuff in your code -- i.e. dirs.createNewFile() and then ANOTHER dir.makeDirs(). Skip all that. If you want to, you can wrap everything below `mkdirs()` in `if( sdcard.isDirectory() )` -- I updated the answer.